# Error while npm installing gulp 4

Tags: npm, gulp

I am trying to install gulp 4 using below command :

```
sudo npm install git+https://git@github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git#4.0 --save-dev
```

But getting Permission Denied Error :

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b 4.0             https://git@github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git         /Users/abhilashdk/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-52649803
npm ERR! /Users/abhilashdk/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-52649803/.git:     Permission denied
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/abhilashdk/.npm/_logs/2017-09-05T18_05_21_216Z-debug.log
```

Please tell me what is the error and how to correct it?

```
npm -v -> 5.4.0
node -v  -> 8.2.1
```

I am using macOS Sierra.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install gulp 4 using the below command :

```
sudo npm install gulpjs/gulp.git#4.0 --save-dev
```

I generated and added ssh keys. After this got the below error :

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

But anyway gulp 4 is installed :)